# Turbine syntax highlighting

Tags: css, netbeans, syntax-highlighting, turbine

I'm trying to get Turbine CSS syntax highlighting (for the cssp files) in netbeans but i've been not able to find any highlighter or way to do it.

Do you have any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can extrapolate for Netbeans the following post:

http://webdevkit.net/2010/08/turbine-syntax-highlight-mode-for-coda

Regards.